VeraCode static scan CWE-73: External Control of File Name or Path
My application Spring Boot 3 Mvc has the following controller method:
@RequestMapping(value = "/addToCart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addToCart(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        String[] quantity= request.getParameterValues("qty");
        String[] itemNumbers = request.getParameterValues("itemNumber");

        return addToCartHelper(webRequest, request, qtys, itemNumbers);
    }

VeraCode points to CWE-73 vulnerability on line "return addToCartHelper(webRequest, request, qtys, itemNumbers);"

CWE-73: External Control of File Name or Path: Link to description

Inside "addToCartHelper" method I access the MongoDB repository and generate the view URL for the redirect.
I don't interact with the file system.
Can you tell me how to fix the vulnerability?

What is **CWE-73 vulnerability **. You expect us to know that...

@M.Deinum Sorry, I edited the question description, added a link to the description.

Your code has several problems from a security perspective, but first and foremost you're not even validating the parameters before you're using them.  When receiving input from a user you always
1.)  Assert that it's malicious
2.)  Treat it as such
It's not clear why you're getting a path vuln flag, maybe see what happens if you send in <url>/addToCart/../../ and see what happens?  Maybe at the root context of your application you're not defending against directory traversal which is more what this smells like based on the CWE-73.
But for sure, even if you clear CWE-73, you're not validating that the parameter values are
1.)  In a valid range //String.length > 0 && String.length <= Integer.MAX_VALUE to get you started
2.)  Are actually numbers (since that's what you expect) // [0-9]+
Afterwards, before you pass that data to the database, ensure they're using parameterized queries (or whatever the equivalent is in MongoDB).
At any rate, I'd answer the traversal question by using the testing guide I linked, and then determine if it's valid.  You can also use a tool like DirBuster against a running instance of your web app to test and see if you're not handling paths correctly.

I just checked the possibility of accessing the controller with the addition of ../../ - this request is filtered at the Spring Web level (it does not find the corresponding endpoint and view, after which it redirects to the error page)
I also tried to run through the array of parameters and try to parse the value of org.owasp.encoder.Encode.forJava(inputValue) into an integer. This did not bring any changes...
I am confused =((

@HeorhiUtseuski in your situation I would reach out to Veracode support as they have dedicated staff to help you out.  The only way I could help you further is if you create a demo application that reproduces the issue that I could access.
